# What is the meaning of parameters starting with tilde ~ in functions?

Tags: syntax, ocaml

What is the meaning of parameters starting with tilde `~` in functions, like in the this example:

```
let draw_line ~img ~color ~p0:(x0,y0) ~p1:(x1,y1) = ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are named parameters where the label is the same as the formal parameter name:

```
# let divide ~num ~den = num /. den;;
val divide : num:float -> den:float -> float = <fun>
# divide ~den:10.0 ~num:30.0;;
- : float = 3.
```

This is described under **function definition** [here](https://v2.ocaml.org/releases/4.14/htmlman/expr.html).